# Request Error: 'Referrer Policy: strict-origin-when-cross-origin' in Angular when build in --prod mode

Tags: angular, cross-domain, ng-build, referrer-policy

I deployed my Angular application to `https` domain. And the API domain is `http`.

When I build my Angular app using `--prod` I got an error in requests that `Referrer Policy: strict-origin-when-cross-origin`, However when I build without `--prod` the requests are working perfectly.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 6):

If you're asking it means you're probably using a Chromium-based browser such as Brave, Chrome or others.

When connecting to an API, the request should pass a privacy policy.
Chromium-based browser have recently changed the default policy.

You may want to have a look at the official [reference about the Strict Origin when Cross Origin](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2020/07/referrer-policy-new-chrome-default) as this could eventually evolve again.

Note that when a Chromium-based browser is giving you some error, also trying with Firefox may give you an extra error message and help you understand what is blocking.

Comment: Edge now has the same restrictions. Jan 2021